# Error Could not load file or assembly RestSharp, Version=105.0.1.0

Tags: restsharp

Started getting error: Could not load file or assembly RestSharp, Version=105.0.1.0

after upgrade to mandrill nuget brought in newer version or restSharpSigned 105.0.1.0

getting same error in all other libs using restsharp like twilio

An exception of type 'System.IO.FileLoadException' occurred in Twilio.Api.dll but was not handled in user code

Comment: I'm using Twilio 3.6.25 because its restsharp dependency works fine

Comment: well it really is mandrill latest nugget having restsharpsigned version, that I belive caused the problem for other components dependent or restsharp to throw this error.